# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 416, 416, 3)

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, yolo

I am currently learning how to use Yolo for object detection, I came across this error after resizing my image to 416x416:

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 416, 416, 3) for input Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 416, 416, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (32, 416, 3).

I was reading other similar post saying that this error is because my image input is not the right shape.

But when I called image.shape on my resized image, it outputs (416, 416, 3).
I also tried
`image_data = np.expand_dims(image_paded, axis = 0)`, it outputs (1, 416, 416, 3) and it still gives me the same error above.

Any advice on how to go about troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: I  don't think after using expand_dims the message is the same, it is probably different.

Comment: i am wondering where the error number "32" coming from...

Comment: The default batch size.

Comment: that dosent make sense because I set the input size to 416 and batch size to 4.

Comment: `predict()` and `fit()` are different methods, and I guess you set 4 in `fit()` not in `predict()`